# trigger rule none_skipped is not working as expected

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a situation where I need to use none_skipped trigger rule but it is behaving strangely. Here is my scenario.

Branch Task B, 
if true T1 >> T2 >> joinTask
if false F1 >> F2 >> joinTask

if condition in B false then T1 is skipped but T2 is executed as trigger rule was 'all_done'( i need T2 even if T1 fails ). So I made T2 as 'none_skipped'

I was expecting T2 to get triggered if T1 is success or failed or upstream failed ( As per the documentation). Instead T2 is getting triggered as soon as the dag starts. It is executed before any other task.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was only recently fixed, in airflow 1.10.5:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5902

Try updating airflow to 1.10.5